# Magento 1.9 breadcrumbs always empty

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, breadcrumbs

I'm working on a magento ecommerce, I'm not the one who configured it or anything, I'm just doing his CSS, however, the site does not display the breadcrumbs.

Inside the "page / html / breadcrumbs.phtml" file I made a var_dump in the $ crumbs variable and it is always empty.

In the XML only in one situation the breadcrumbs is displayed in the frontend, when I enter the code inside the "default" tag if I put this code inside "customer_account_login" nothing will be displayed on the front.

Code of breadcrumbs.phtml:

```
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>">
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <strong><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here part of code of "customer.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <layout version="0.1.0">

        <default>
            <!-- Mage_Customer -->
            <reference name="top.links">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
            </reference>

            <!-- HERE BREADCRUMBS DISPLAYS ON ALL PAGES THE SAME CONTENT "HOME / MY ACCOUNT" -->
            <reference name="breadcrumbs">
                <action method="addCrumb">
                    <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                    <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
                </action>
                <action method="addCrumb">
                    <crumbName>My Account</crumbName>
                    <crumbInfo><label>My Account</label><title>My Account</title><link>/customer/account/</link></crumbInfo>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </default>

        <!-- Load this update on every page when customer is logged in -->
        <customer_logged_in>
            <reference name="top.links">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            </reference>
        </customer_logged_in>

        <!-- Load this update on every page when customer is logged out -->
        <customer_logged_out>
            <reference name="top.links">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            </reference>
            <remove name="reorder"></remove>
        </customer_logged_out>

        <!-- Layout for customer login page -->
        <customer_account_login translate="label">
            <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
            <!-- Mage_Customer -->
            <remove name="right"/>
            <remove name="left"/>

            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </customer_account_login>
```

If I move the breadcrumbs code from "< default >" to the "< customer_account_login translate="label" >" for example, all screens returns the breadcrumbs as null.

I have no idea what's going on. I just wish all the screens had their breadcrumbs being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check that breadcrumbs are actually enabled in the back end admin panel like below.

[image: Breadcrumbs]

Comment: Okay. Maybe this will help you? https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/Adding-Breadcrumbs-to-Customer-Account-Pages/td-p/2449